# Issues with ttimageview setframe doesnt work

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I have a ttimageview that works pretty well with the frame set initially with the constructor. However, it doesnt work  if I do something like  [ttimageview setFrame: someFrame]; it doesnt work.

Can anyone kindly advice how to solve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems like I needed to remove the image, release it, re-alloc it with the proper frame to fix the frame issues. not sure why setFrame didnt work. Ended up writing a new method.